# Issue in coding plugin wordpress with add_option or set_transient method

Tags: php, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm beginer in coding of wordpress plugin, and i follow a tutorial to do it.
In my tutorial, the person says than with the method set_transient(), we can create a new record in the table wp_option of the database of wordpress.

I tried to do this and i checked my table, the table, the new record hasn't been created. So i searched on the web and I found the methode add_option() to do the same action. And it don't works too. I checked with a log file if my method was correctly used in my code and it is the case, my method, is well called, but the record isn't created in my table.
I let here my code to show you :

My plugin main file :

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Activity
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Activity
Plugin URI: https://www.example.fr/
Description: Example.
Author: Me
Version: 1.0.0
Author URI: https://www.me.fr/
*/

//Ensure the plugin can't be started outside of Wordpress
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )
    exit;

//get the enitre path from plugin
require plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'vendor/autoload.php';

$plugin = new Activity\DuplicatePost\Plugin(__FILE__);
?>
```

my classe file :

```
<?php

namespace Activity\DuplicatePost;

class Plugin
{
    const TRANSIENT_DUPLICATE_POST_ACTIVATED = 'duplicate_post_activated';

    public function __construct(string $file)
    {
       register_activation_hook($file, [$this, 'plugin_activation']);
       add_action('admin_notices', [$this, 'notice_activation']);
    }

    public function plugin_activation()
    {
        //Check the function is well called, sending a message log in my log file.
        error_log('ok',3,'log_file.txt');
        //Create a column in the database, wp-content table, bool at true when we start the plugin.
        set_transient(self::TRANSIENT_DUPLICATE_POST_ACTIVATED, true);
        add_option( self::TRANSIENT_DUPLICATE_POST_ACTIVATED, true );
    }

    public function notice_activation()
    {
        if (get_transient(self::TRANSIENT_DUPLICATE_POST_ACTIVATED))
        {

        }

    }
}
```

How can i make works this fonctionnality? thanks you for help.

Comment: Sounds like the tutorial is probably bad then ... because creating new _columns_ would be absurd to begin with here. WordPress uses a "key - value" data model, so this should create new _records_, but not change anything about the table's _structure_.

Comment: it'scorrect, sorry it's me, i did an error in my question, it's a records, not a column, i will edit my question, thank you to make notice it !

Comment: So your `plugin_activation` method gets triggered when you activate the plugin, you get the entry in the error log?

Comment: FYI, you should decide what you actually want to use here, transients, or options. The purpose of transients is to provide a sort of "cache" for data, that is supposed to expire at some point. And options are to store general site settings, stuff like that. Which one you should actually use, depends on what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: ok, yes i get well the entry in the error_log. I tried to suppress the line : set_transient(self::TRANSIENT_DUPLICATE_POST_ACTIVATED, true); and test only add_option method, but in the table wp_option, i have still nothing added when i active my plugin, and its the same result if i suppress the line : add_option( 'simplit_duplicate_post_activated', true ); and test with the set_transiet() method only, i don't have result in my database

Comment: Which table(s) are you checking? Options should go into `wp_options`, with transients I am not actually sure right now. What happens when you try to get the value using `get_option`, and output that somewhere on your page?

Comment: Yes i checked the wp_options table. I just tried the command line error_log(get_option( self::TRANSIENT_DUPLICATE_POST_ACTIVATED),3,'log_file.txt'); that you gave me. i obtain the output "1", so it seems than the options is well created with the boolean value, it isn't?

Comment: Yes, looks like it. You did not specify a default value via the second parameter for `get_option`, so in case it did not find the option, it should return false (which in the string context of your error log, should just be "nothing" then) - but since you are getting `1`, that should really mean it stored the option properly.

Comment: Ok, I don't know why i can't see the change in the database, but i didn't knew the commandline get_option(). this will help to progress in my coding. If the option is well created, it's what iwanted. I will check by myself why i can't see in database. But it isn't the importnat for now. So Thank you very much for your help, have a nice day !